# Height of dropdown list of spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

how can i solve the problem like the image below.It's a dropdown list of a spinner which is the size of text is 60sp. Can I resize the height of each row of dropdown list ?

Here is the [image](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/68370_426443477409188_1326178162_n.jpg) that I want to do in my spinner.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: I just use normal android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item to set my ArrayAdapter view.

Answer (score 0):

Create an XML layout for the row and define the height, then specify it as the dropdown view for the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

You could just define wrap_content in the spinner in the xml file.